# Lookup extension method

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

Rather than create a whole new class implementing `ILookup<T>` is it possible to add an extension method to dictionary which caters for it? I'm thinking something along the following:

```
public static void LookupAdd(this Dictionary<T, List<V>> dict, T key, V item)
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        dict.Add(key, new List<T>());
    }
    dict[key].Add(item);
}
```

This fails to compile saying it can't identify the types. I'm guessing that my generic parameters are too complex (particularly `List<V>`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try...

```
public static void LookupAdd<T,V>(this Dictionary<T, List<V>> dict, T key, V item)
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        dict.Add(key, new List<V>());
    }
    dict[key].Add(item);
}
```

UPDATE:

Notice that you should have

```
new List<V>()
```

where you have

```
new List<T>()
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I've got half a dozen other helpers in this class all with the generic definition in and I completly forgot about it when doing this one! Marked you as the answer as you were first there with it.

Answer (score 8):

You have forgotten to add the generic parameter syntax:

```
 public static void LookupAdd<T, V>(this Dictionary<T, List<V>> dictionary, T key, V item)
 {
 }
```

The `<T, V>` is missing.

Comment: also you can't call `dict.Add(key, new List<T>());` it should be `dict.Add(key, new List<V>());`

Comment: Thanks for solving it. You got a +1 from me but I gave the answer to Eric. Wish I could give it to both!